# Duplex Printing from button inside DialogNotebook on Mac

Tags: mac-os-x, printing, dialog-window

All,

I have the following code which generates a window containing the variable *PrintOut* and a Print button. When the print button is pressed the contents of the window are sent to the printer and simultaneously a pdf is generated.

```
PrintOut = "Some stuff - plots, tables etc.";

DialogInput[
  DialogNotebook[
   Column[{PrintOut, 
     Row[{Button["Print", 
        DialogReturn[NotebookPrint[PrintOut, "filename.pdf"];
         NotebookPrint[
          CreateDocument[PrintOut, Visible -> False, 
           PageHeaders -> {{"a", "b", DateString[]}, {"a", "b", 
              DateString[]}}]]]], CancelButton[]}]}]], 
  ShowStringCharacters -> False, 
  WindowTitle -> "This Window " <> DateString[]];
```

The problem arises when *PrintOut* contains enough stuff to be spread over multiple pages. I wish to have the pages print on both sides but can't figure out how to do it.

I have the print settings within MMA set to duplex and when I print a notebook using the front end I get duplex but it does not work for DialogNotebook. I am using MMA8

Help appreciated.